# Converting Date to day-mon-year format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to convert dates like this:

```
3/2/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

to this:

```
2-MAR-2016
```

Comment: Do you have a string in that format that you want to convert to a date?  A string that you want to convert into a different string?  Dates do not have formats.  Strings have formats.  And why is this tagged for MySQL and SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) if you are using Oracle?

Comment: These are both date objects.  Can I cast these or format one differently in my SQL query that I'm using in SSRS to achieve this?

Comment: A date does not have a format.  You can convert the date to a string in a particular format using `to_char`, i.e. `to_char(your_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')` or `to_char(your_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')`.  But realistically your reporting tool will also have options to format dates in whatever format you want.

Comment: Just to be safe, I added a solution for both `oracle` and `mySQL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ORACLE You can use to_char(your_date, format)

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(your_Date ,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
 FROM DUAL;
```

for mysql

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(your_Date ,'%d-%m-%Y') 
 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, (and also not for being a tag nazi!)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's default date format is `YYYY-mm-dd`. We can use the `TO_CHAR` method to convert to a specific format.

```
TO_CHAR(date, 'FMDD-MON-YYYY')
```

Breakdown

`FMDD`- Apperantly, just using `DD` as recommended in the documentation does not format days with a leading 0. You need to use `FMDD`.

`MON`- Abbreviated month name

`%YYYY`- Long year format

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm

In my-sql, the same could be accomplished with the `DATE_FORMAT` method

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%b-%y')
```

Slightly different formatter options

Scroll down to the Datetime Format Elements

Comment: Actually, `DD` does return the leading zero in Oracle (`SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-03-02', 'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM DUAL` returns `02-MAR-2016`). To suppress the leading zero use `TO_CHAR(date, 'FMDD-MON-YYYY')`.

Comment: You sure about that. From the documentation I just read, I found `Day of month (1-31).`

Comment: I'm sure; I tested it. Do you have Oracle available? If not, use SQLFiddle and give the query a try. `DD` = day with leading zeros; `FMDD` = day without leading zeros. You have to be careful with `FM` though - it's an on off switch: `FMDD-MM-YYYY` will suppress the leading zero in day *and* month because the `FM` switch is on. To suppress for day but not for month, turn the `FM` switch on for day and back off for month: `FMDD-FMMM-YYYY`.